# How to fix JavaFX WebView geometric shapes (triangles) that have wildly inconsistent sizes?

Tags: html, javafx, webview

I have a very nicely-behaved set of triangles ([Unicode 25B0 - 25C5](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/geometric_shapes/list.htm)) in HTML, rendered in Chrome:

[image]

In JavaFX WebView:

[image]

Argh! It looks awful and inconsistent in sizes. What's going on here???

Source code:

```css
p.test1 { font-family: sans-serif; }
p.test2 { font-family: serif; }
```

```html
<html><body>
<p class="test1">
test1 &#x25b2;&#x25b3;&#x25b4;&#x25b5;&#x25b6;&#x25b7;&#x25b8;&#x25b9;&#x25ba;&#x25bb;&#x25bc;&#x25bd;&#x25be;&#x25bf;&#x25c0;&#x25c1;&#x25c2;&#x25c3;&#x25c4;&#x25c5;
</p>
<p class="test2">
test2 &#x25b2;&#x25b3;&#x25b4;&#x25b5;&#x25b6;&#x25b7;&#x25b8;&#x25b9;&#x25ba;&#x25bb;&#x25bc;&#x25bd;&#x25be;&#x25bf;&#x25c0;&#x25c1;&#x25c2;&#x25c3;&#x25c4;&#x25c5;
</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I have no answer to this, but maybe you could also mention the JavaFX version you are using. This might help a bit.